# Need help with wiring new Thermostat. Original 3 wire to Sensi Emerson

Tags: electrical, hvac, thermostat-c-wire

Hoping to get some help with this.  The current old thermostat has a R (red wire) ,G (black wire, switches to blue at the furnace end) , and W (white wire).  I noticed at the furnace side the white wire was connected to both the W1 and W2 terminal.  When i called Emerson they said i would need a "C" wire to make it work despite them advertising it as not needing a "C" wire.  When i plug in the 3 connection points (R,W,G) into the Sensi APP, it comes back as invalid connection point.  However, if i add that it has W1, W2 (since the white wire is connected to both those terminals, it comes back as compatible (R,G,W1,W2).  So what I'm thinking is I connect the R (old) -> RH (new), the G (old) -> G (new), and the W (old) -> W/E (new), and daisy chain (jump) the W/E to the W2 on the back of the Sensi.  Any info on whether this will work would be appreciated.  Or any other tips to getting it to work.  Its a heat only system.  I have provided some pics.  Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Looks like two of your pictures didn't work; post the URLs of them and someone will be along to edit them into your question.

Comment: What sort of furnace are you controlling, and do you care about being able to control the fan separately from the heat?

Comment: What did your old thermostat control (heat and blower, cooler, etc)?  BTW,  Emerson says quite clearly that it will operate on its internal battery if no C wire, but will not support wifi.  I found it just as easy to buy a DC power supply and "hot-wire" power to the Emerson thermostat as is clearly explained in the installation manual